# Django redirect() doesn't redirect but rather refreshes the same page

Tags: python, django, redirect

view.py

```
@login_required(login_url='index', redirect_field_name=None)
def new_character(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      character_form = CharacterForm(request.POST)
      if character_form.is_valid():
        new_character = character_form.save(commit=False)
        new_character.creator = request.user
        new_character.save()
        # If new_character has a primary key (pk) then it
        # means it was saved to the database.
        if new_character.pk:
          # TODO: For some reason this doesn't work.
          redirect('list_characters')
    else:
      character_form = CharacterForm()
    return render(request, 'characters/new-character.html', {'character_form': character_form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.list_characters, name='list_characters'),
    path('new/', views.new_character, name='new_character'),
]
```

I checked and `new_character.pk` is coerced to True. However, the redirect doesn't happen and instead the same page is simply refreshed.

Comment: I beleive you will have to return redirect('list_characters') in your nested if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are not returning the `redirect`, which results in the `return render(request, 'characters/new-character.html'...` being hit, changing from:

```
redirect('list_characters')
```

To:

```
return redirect('list_characters')
```

Should solve the issue

Comment: I lost more than an hour on this one... Gosh, programming can be frustrating! Thanks CJ4 and @since9teen94 for helping me out.